# On M10, set "Notifications" as default control/notification in UR corner?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet, bq, aquaris, m10

On the M10, can "Notfications" (green envelope) be set as the default tool in the notifications/controls area of the user interface (tablet upper-right corner) so that swiping down from UR corner brings the user directly to the notifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it cannot. There is no "default" indicator which is opened when swiping down. Swiping down from the position of the notifications indicator itself, will show the notifications.